# update_resource_params gives Unpermitted parameters error - Devise Invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-invitable

I am trying to implement invitation on existing users in my app, using Devise Invitable.

At first glance this fails, because Devise Invitable is best used on new users - i.e. non-registered.

But this is what my `User::InvitationsController` looks like (truncated for brevity):

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
include ApplicationHelper
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_filter :update_sanitized_params, only: :update

  # PUT /resource/invitation

  def create
    invited_user = User.where(email: params[:user][:email])
    if !invited_user.empty?
      invitation_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(resource_class, :invitation_token, update_resource_params[:invitation_token])
      self.resource = resource_class.where(invitation_token: invitation_token).first
      family_tree = self.resource.invited_by.family_tree
      family_tree.memberships.create(:user_id => user.id, relation: update_resource_params[:relation])
      resource.create_membership_both_ways(params[:user][:invitation_token], params[:user][:relation])
      resource.skip_password = true
      resource.update_attributes update_resource_params.except(:invitation_token)
      redirect_to my_tree_path
     else
       super
     end
  end

  protected

  def update_sanitized_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation) do |u|
      u.permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation, :invitation_token, :invitation_relation,:avatar, :avatar_cache, :relation)
    end
  end

  def update_resource_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:accept_invitation) do |u|
      u.permit(:email)
    end
  end
end
```

When I use pry for debugging, this is what happens when I poke around `invitation_token`:

```
[1] pry(#<Users::InvitationsController>)> invitation_token
=> false
[2] pry(#<Users::InvitationsController>)> update_resource_params
Unpermitted parameters: email
=> {"name"=>"", "invitation_relation"=>"uncle"}
```

Thoughts on what may be causing this, or how I can get rid of this `unpermitted paramters :email` problem?

**Edit 1**

These are the relevant routes:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :invitations => 'users/invitations', :confirmations => 'confirmations' }

  devise_scope :user do
    post "users/invitation/sign_in" => "users/invitations#invite_sign_in"
  end
```

**Edit 2**

In my `application_controller.rb` I have a method that I added `:email` and it seems to have stopped that error:

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    # Once I added :email to this method, it stopped throwing the unpermitted error
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation) do |u|
      u.permit(:name, :email, :last_name, :invitation_relation)
    end
  end
```

Comment: im assuming you have something like this in your routes :controllers => { :invitations=> "invitations"}

Comment: also does this help https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/wiki/Devise-Invitable-with-Strong-Parameters

Comment: @Richlewis I updated the question with my routes file info, but you are correct. I do have that in my routes file. Re that link...so the exact code snippet doesn't help at all - just tried it. At the very least, the method names are different so unless `update_resource_params` calls `resource_params` I don't see how it would help. Other than that, it seems to be a Rails 3 version of what I have there, but less powerful. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Richlewis I also tried a few permutations of that line and it still doesn't work...soo...not sure what's up.

Comment: do you have a configure_permitted_parameters method in your application controller? as you can see your error is to do with not allowing the email attribute, something like this maybe devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation) << [:email] and maybe remove the update_resource_params from your controller

Comment: @Richlewis So I added `:email` and that seems to have solved the issue - but I didn't have to remove `update_resource_params` even though your suggestion sounds very reasonable. Do you mean remove the override method definition, or remove the call to it in the `Devise.token_generator` call?

Comment: @Richlewis If you add that solution as an answer, I will accept it. I updated my question with `Edit 2` that showed exactly what worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Devise and configuring permitted_params it is best to do this in the application controller,
 you can do it one of two ways

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation) do |u|
   u.permit(:name, :email, :last_name, :invitation_relation)
 end
end
```

OR

```
def configure_permitted_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation) << [:name, :email, :last_name, :invitation_relation]
end
```